# Finding the probability when knowing the number of successes after n attempts

Tags: probability

Assuming I have made an experiment, and after n attempts I had k successes, how can I know what is my probability of succeeding in a single attempt?

Just for some realism, the numbers I'm happening to be working on at the moments are:

n=56
k=4

Comment: You can probably assume it's near k/n, but you can't tell for sure if that's the actual probability of if you got lucky.

Comment: You can only estimate the probability, not deduce it, no matter how many trials you make. But the estimate gets better and better, if you make more and more trials.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This question can't be answered without knowing your prior beliefs about the experiment. See [Rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession) at Wikipedia for a derivation of various results under various assumptions about your prior beliefs. Two prominent estimates that may be relevant for you are $\frac kn$ and $\frac{k+1}{n+2}$.